# Google Cloud computing SSH closes service

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, python

I am really new on this. I am running ubuntu on google cloud computing. I connect to the compute engine using ssh and I start an Ethereum node. However, when I close the ssh connection the node seen to go down as well. It si the same for any other program I ran.

My purpose is to run the node and a python script in the machine. Do I need to keep the ssh connection alive to keep these programs running? I assume the answer is not, but I do not know how to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy, all processes executed in your SSH session would be closed when you disconnect. Easiest way to keep they running after logout - use `screen`. Run your processes in screen, detach and logout. In that case your processes work after your logout.

Comment: Awesome, looked into it and it works! Thanks. Learned also that tmux will work as well